# Every convex form of functions is convex?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The function $f(x,y)=a(x-b)^2+c(y-d)^2$ is convex.
It is well known and I can prove it ($a>0, b>0$).

What if $F(x,y)=a(g(x,y)-b)^2+c(h(x,y)-d)^2$?

1. Is $F$ always a convex function?

Or

2. if $g$ and $h$ is convex, then is $F$ always a convex function?

Comment: Re 1.: how about taking $a = 1, b = 0, c = 0$ and $g(x, y) = \log x$. You get a concave function over the region $x > e$.

Comment: Re 2,: take $g(x, y) = -\log x$ and $a = 1, b = 0, c = 0$, and notice $-\log x$ is convex over its real domain.